# Maximum .NET achievable memory?

Tags: .net, memory

Which is the maximum amount of memory one can achieve in .NET managed code? Does it depend on the actual architecture (32/64 bits)?

Comment: Yes there is.. Give it a shot and watch the runtime bomb out at around 900MB on 32 bit architectures.. Or just run a decent, not even large, dataset.. Sad really.

Comment: Well if you need a fact then you better load it up and look out for OutOfMemory exception when it reaches it.. The problem is you only have to run a couple of such apps (you know decent size) and voila:

CLR is efficient theorists get all loopy about it.

Comment: I can confirm the 900 MB limit and it is the limit in practice. I have seen it repeatedly for the past 6 years in 3 different WinForms applications. In the first years it was approximately 700 MB and the maximum I have ever seen is approximately 1050 MB.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no hard, exact figure for .NET code.

If you run on 32 bit Windows; your *process* can address up to 2 GB, 3 GB if the /3GB switch is used on Windows Server 2003.

If you run a 64 bit process on a 64 bit box your *process* can address up to 8 TB of address space, if that much RAM is present.

This is not the whole story however, since the CLR takes some overhead for each process. At the same time, .NET will try to allocate new memory in chunks; and if the address space is fragmented, that might mean that you cannot allocate more memory, even though some are available.

Comment: That is not true. Windows on x86 limits the user mode partition size to 8 TB (8192 GB).

Comment: "can address the whole 64 bit address space, if that much RAM is present" no way that is correct and should be edited..

Comment: 32bit process under 64bit Windows can access 4GB of user space (with large address aware... same criterion as to access 3GB under /3GB switch).

Comment: @driis, on a 64 bit machine the limit is 8TB not the entire 64 bit address space

Comment: @myself - obviously I meant on 64 bit. Doh!

Comment: You are all right about the 8 TB limit on x64, I edited the answer to fix that. (Guess i was a bit too fast when writing that answer :-)

Comment: You can address more than the size of your RAM, because allocated virtual memory doesn't have to be in RAM, it can be in the page file.

Answer (score 7):

In C# 2.0 and 3.0 there is also a 2G limit on the size of a single object in managed code.

Answer (score 7):

The amount of memory your .NET process can address depends both on whether it is running on a 32/64 bit machine and whether or not it it running as a CPU agnostic or CPU specific process.

By default a .NET process is CPU agnostic so it will run with the process type that is natural to the version of Windows.  In 64 bit it will be a 64 bit process, and in 32 bit it will be a 32 bit process.  You can force a .NET process though to target a particular CPU and say make it run as a 32 bit process on a 64 bit machine.

If you exclude the large address aware setting, the following are the various breakdowns

- 32 bit process can address 2GB
- 64 bit process can address 8TB

Here is a link to the full breakdown of addressable space based on the various options Windows provides.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx

Answer (score 5):

For 64 bit Windows the virtual memory size is 16 TB divided equally between user and kernel mode, so user processes can address 8 TB (8192 GB). That is less than the entire 16 [EB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) space addressable by 64 bits, but it is still a whole lot more than what we're used to with 32 bits.

Answer (score 5):

I have recently been doing extensive profiling around memory limits in .NET on a 32bit process. We all get bombarded by the idea that we can allocate up to 2.4GB (2^31) in a .NET application but unfortuneately this is not true :(. The application process has that much space to use and the operating system does a great job managing it for us, however, .NET itself seems to have its own overhead which accounts for aproximately 600-800MB for typical real world applications that push the memory limit. This means that as soon as you allocate an array of integers that takes about 1.4GB, you should expect to see an OutOfMemoryException().

Obviously in 64bit, this limit occurs way later (let's chat in 5 years :)), but the general size of everything in memory also grows (I am finding it's ~1.7 to ~2 times) because of the increased word size.

What I know for sure is that the Virtual Memory idea from the operating system definitely does NOT give you virtually endless allocation space within one process. It is only there so that the full 2.4GB is addressable to all the (many) applications running at one time.

I hope this insight helps somewhat.

I originally answered something related here (I am still a newby so am not sure how I am supposed to do these links):

[Is there a memory limit for a single .NET process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200348/is-there-a-memory-limit-for-a-single-net-3-5-process/1910974#1910974)

Comment: Why did you want to post this same answer multiple times?

Comment: Sorry, am a noob. How do you link related questions and answers on this site?

Answer (score 3):

The .NET runtime can allocate all the free memory available for user-mode programs in its host. Mind that it doesn't mean that all of that memory will be dedicated to your program, as some (relatively small) portions will be dedicated to internal CLR data structures.
In 32 bit systems, assuming a 4GB or more setup (even if PAE is enabled), you should be able to get at the very most roughly 2GB allocated to your application. On 64 bit systems you should be able to get 1TB. For more information concerning windows memory limits, please review [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx).
Every figure mentioned there has to be divided by 2, as windows reserves the higher half of the address space for usage by code running in kernel mode (ring 0).
Also, please mind that whenever for a 32 bit system the limit exceeds 4GB, use of [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) is implied, and thus you still can't really exceed the 2GB limit unless the OS supports 4gt, in which case you can reach up to 3GB.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a 32 bits environment you are limited to a 4GB address-space but Windows claims about half. On a 64 bits architecture it is, well, a lot bigger. I believe it's 4G * 4G

And on the Compact Framework it usually is in the order of a few hundred MB

Comment: Saying 4G * 4G will mislead people to think 16G.  Really, 4G is 2^32 bytes, so nearly 4 billion.  and the 64 bit limit is 2^64 = (2^32)*(2^32), which is (4 billion)*(4 billion) and that's a lot more than 16G.

Answer (score 0):

I think other answers being quite naive, in real world after 2GB of memory consumption your application will behave really badly. In my experience GUIs generally go massively clunky, unsusable after lots of memory consumptions.

This was my experience, obviously actual cause of this can be objects grows too big so all operations on those objects takes too much time.

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post has detailed findings on x86 and x64 max memory. It also has a small tool (source available) which allows easy easting of the different memory options:
http://www.guylangston.net/blog/Article/MaxMemory.