# MWMCR::evaluatefunction error out of memory

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-deployment, out-of-memory

when I run my application I got this exception

[a busy cat http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/5619/bugxt.jpg](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/5619/bugxt.jpg)

I understood that the program is out of memory .. are there any other possible meaning for that exception?

given that I am calling a dll files (deployment from matlab)

thank you all

Comment: what other `meaning` you expect here?

Comment: I expect some problems in MCR (matlab compiler run-time)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible, just use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see your processe's `WorkingSet`.
For 32 bit Windows systems maximum available memory for .NET Provecesses is arround 2GB, but it can be less based on your version configuration. Here is the [SO Link on subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716798/maximum-net-achievable-memory).

Considering the fact that you use `matlab`, so probably make  a massive or complex calculations, you, probably, create a lot of objects/values to pass to DLL functions, which can be a one possible sources of bottleneck. But this is only a guess, cause you need to measure you program to figure out real problem.

Regards.

**Note**: *check your old questions and accept an answer you prefer among responses you got for every question, your rate is too low !*