# Why does the amount of memory available to x86 applications fluctuate in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have an application made in vb.net on x86 architecture and it is running out of memory when assigning 400,000 records to a Dataset and I see in the diagnostic session that 1.2 gb is loaded and it crashes, it is not supposed to be for x86 applications has 2gb available.

Because in some connections to several servers it oscillates between 1.2 gb, 1.5 gb and 1.8 gb, it is possible to tell it to take the 2 gb it has for x86 app?

Comment: Store your data in data classes instead. This will save the overhead going along with Datasets. You can then use [dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/) of EF Core to load/save data and data binding to display data.

Comment: I found the answer in this link [Use of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716798/maximum-net-achievable-memory)