# Can I set LARGEADDRESSAWARE from within Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, large-address-aware

I have a .NET assembly that needs to be 32-Bit and needs to be `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`.

I know how to do this with `EditBin`, but I wonder if there is a built-in way in Visual Studio 2010? Or alternatively, did someone write an MSBuild Task for this?

*Edit:* This is for a C# app, so no linker options sadly :(

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do it as a Post-build task. In "Build Events" tab, put following command

```
editbin /largeaddressaware $(TargetPath)
```

into the "Post-build event command line:"

This is the case for VS2008. I think it should work in the same way for VS2010.

Comment: This works great, but if you use ClickOnce to publish, be aware that it publishes using the files in the **`obj`** folder and NOT the ones in **`bin`**.  To cover both normal build output (used for debugging / running locally) as well as ClickOnce publishes, you need to run `editbin` against **both** directories in the Post Build event.  I'd also suggest wrapping the `TargetPath` macro in quotes.

Comment: Be sure to check out Kirill's answer. His nuget package is very helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182578/55721

Answer (score 99):

Building on @RouMao's answer, you may get an error message saying that *editbin* cannot be found.  Ensure that the environment in the post-build event command line is setup properly by specifying as follows:

```
call "$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\tools\vsvars32.bat"
editbin /largeaddressaware $(TargetPath)
```

Another thing to understand is that your `LARGEADDRESSAWARE` enabled application will not run in debugging mode when (under the `Debug` tab in your project properties) the `Enable the Visual Studio hosting process` check-box is checked (which it is by default), because the `vshost.exe` is not properly flagged.

Uncheck that box to debug your application using `LARGEADDRESSAWARE`.

Comment: for VS 2013 you need to change the first line to `call "$(DevEnvDir)..\tools\vsvars32.bat"`

Comment: and for those who are working with VS 2012 the first line is `call "$(VS110COMNTOOLS)..\tools\vsvars32.bat"`

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your `$(TargetPath)` in quotes `"$(TargetPath)"`

Comment: For VS2010, I also use `$(DevEnvDir)` as mentiond by @WiiMaxx

Comment: Quick update - DevEnvDir no llonger works as of VS2017 due to changes in the paths (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805662/vsvars32-bat-in-visual-studio-2017).  I had to end up using $(VS140COMNTOOLS)

Comment: "Building on @RouMao's answer" ... I guess their name has changed, which answer was it? The accepted one?

Answer (score 24):

This is a NuGet package that can set LargeAddressAware on your binary after it's built: https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/LargeAddressAware

It doesn't require editbin.exe as it has a managed app to set the flag programmatically: https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/LargeAddressAware/blob/master/SetLargeAddressAware/LargeAddressAware.cs

**Update:**
To use it, just install the package and add this property in your .csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <LargeAddressAware>true</LargeAddressAware>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: So largeaddressaware is set automatically once I have added this nuget package? Or do I need to do something in my code?

Comment: Add the NuGet package and set <LargeAddressAware>true</LargeAddressAware> to turn it on. Make sure that the .targets file from the NuPkg is included in your build. To do this, build your project using http://msbuildlog.com and search for "LargeAddressAware" in the structured log.

Comment: *Massively* simpler, despite the need to edit the project file manually. At least you don't have to deal with environment variables and trying to install the correct version of the VC++ build tools all that insanity. I do recommend placing the `<LargeAddressAware>` tag inside the `<PropertyGroup>`s that are conditional on the x86 platform, though.

Comment: Do you need to do this for DLL files in the project as well as the exe, or just the exe is all that is required?

Comment: @rolls just the exe

Comment: @KirillOsenkov Does it still work with .Net 6 ? In my case it didn't ...

Comment: I don’t think it’s needed for .NET 6, as the .exe files generated by it are not managed binaries, but small app host programs that find and start the runtime.

Answer (score 10):

If you compile your Assembly with:

```
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit> <!--Default !false!-->
```

than your resulting assembly will automatically receive `LARGE ADDRESS AWARE` flag.

Tested with VS 2019 (requires Visual Studio 2015+ as per [Why does 'Any CPU (prefer 32-bit)' allow me to allocate more memory than x86 under .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068309/why-does-any-cpu-prefer-32-bit-allow-me-to-allocate-more-memory-than-x86-und)).

So you don't need any special actions in most cases. Your AnyCPU assembly will be executed under x86 + LAA by default.