# Visual Studio 2010(devenv.exe) OutOfMemory exception while building installer for a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, memory, installation

I am using Win 7 64bit edition and I'm working on a C# project. This project has a big database (1,85gb) which makes it a large project. When I am trying to create an installer for this project, while building, it gives me an "OutOfMemory" exception. The problem is probably about the memory available for a process which is 2 GB in windows. So what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Does the setup project contain a 1.85 GB database file inside of it, or is the .msi database itself 1.85 GB?

Comment: setup will contain that database file inside of it. But I don't have any msi file since i couldn't build the project so i don't know msi size yet:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Win 7 64-bit,

*Take a backup of devenv.exe, then do the following steps,

1. Open the Visual Studio command prompt and navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Common7\IDE.
2. Then execute, **editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE devenv.exe**.

To solve this problem in VS2010, read the post [VS 2010 IDE 2GB limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588373/vs-2010-ide-2gb-limt). Hope this helps

Comment: Also, that prompt is probably for VS2008.

Comment: For VS2010, i hope the link mentioned in the answer is helpful.

Comment: FYI you can confirm that VS is already large address aware by calling dumpbin /headers devenv.exe