# XNA with Visual Studio 2012. /Setup not working

Tags: xna, devenv

I'm trying to get XNA working in Visual Studio 2012 so I can use source control but I'm having difficulty with the steps. I've read the numerous pages out there that tell you how to do it such as:
[How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012)
and
http://ryan-lange.com/xna-game-studio-4-0-visual-studio-2012/

But I'm having difficulty finishing the final stage and I can't seem to find anything on google. So the final step is basically, run this from the command prompt in admin mode:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup

The first issue I have is that there is no devenv in my directory, others have said it's because of the express addition where it's called WDExpress.exe instead which does exist. The problem however is that when I replace devenv.exe with that and run it on the cmd prompt nothing actually happens. I get no error, but nothing appears either. It just goes onto a new line and ignores it. I've also tried typing /h at the end, and none of the /h parameters mention /setup, which makes me worried that it might not even exist on the express version. Anyway, could someone please shed some light on this situation for me?

Comment: I can tell you, it is possible to get VS 2012 XNA on the express edition, I did it, But I cant remember what I did now >.> I had trouble on that step too. Try clearing everything about "VS" or "WDExpress" in temp/appdata/roaming, you could also try adding "WDExpress" to the supported products

Comment: Saw a new comment in the other question "The proper paths for WDExpress should be modified to [...]\Common7\IDE\WDExpressExtensions\Microsoft for extensions and [...]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDExpress\11.0\Extensions for clearing the extension cache. "

Comment: Saw that and did that but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 3):

Shortly: try to run Visual Studio as admin, and then start Visual Studio Command Prompt (from Tools menu), and run `devenv.exe /setup`

I had a problem with my MSVS2010 and I also had have to run devenv.exe /setup. If I run MSVS with normal privileges, and started the Visual Studio Command Prompt, I got an error after executing `devenv.exe /setup`: The operation could not be completed.

I was unable to find `devenv.exe` in the way you wrote too, so I tried to run MSVS in admin mode: right click on the program and choose Run as administrator. Opening the VS command prompt again, and executing the `devenv.exe /setup` worked fine for me.

You can also try to run the program in the way smhnkmr suggested on [another SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300899/visual-studio-2010devenv-exe-outofmemory-exception-while-building-installer-fo)

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems installing the XNA extension and I threw the same error at me when I tried to accomplish the last step.
I always got the error: *Operation could not be completed*
I fixed it by creating a shortcut for my WDExpress.exe and adding */setup* to the Target property and starting the shortcut as an administrator.

Good Luck!