# How to enable LARGEADDRESSAWARE for ASP.Net Web application(C#) thruough Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I have seen below links but they did not work for me.

[setting-largeaddressaware-on-a-c-sharp-project-with-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061519/setting-largeaddressaware-on-a-c-sharp-project-with-references)

[how-to-make-a-net-application-large-address-aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346480/how-to-make-a-net-application-large-address-aware)

I dont know why everybody are saying LARGEADDRESSAWARE work on exe but a WebApplication wont generate a exe file

I am using VS2010(32bit)

"Why I want eanble LARGEADDRESSAWARE means becuase I have huge string in my project to work. it is throwing OOM exception. I used StringBuilder. I already posted a Question about that. In the comments our community members suggested LARGEADDRESSAWARE. So that is why I want to enable this feature on my webapplication."

Someone please help me.

Comment: `did not work for me.` what does this mean? What exact issue you are facing?

Comment: it does mean that getting the OOM exception again even I set LARGEADDRESAWARE flag as per the links I put in description