# How to enable IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE in C# source code?

Tags: c#

In Delphi, you can do something like this in the source code.

```
{$SETPEFLAGS IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}
```

How can I do the same thing in C# code so I don't have to use external command such as ***editbin***

Comment: "How can I do the same thing in C# code" - You can't. (We'll maybe appart from hacking your own support into private build of roslyn maybe)

Comment: As an alternative to doing it in the source code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597790/can-i-set-largeaddressaware-from-within-visual-studio

Comment: That option is already turned on by any reasonably up-to-date C# compiler.  Still relying on it is getting pretty stale as well.

Comment: @HansPassant, this is true, but I can't find any documentation for it. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905703/compiling-c-sharp-with-any-cpu-sets-application-can-handle-large-2gb-addresse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do the same thing in C# code so I don't have to use external command such as `editbin`?

You cannot. You would need to use an external tool.