# Why does 'Any CPU (prefer 32-bit)' allow me to allocate more memory than x86 under .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, out-of-memory, .net-4.5

According to many SO answers and [this widely cited blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/), a .NET 4.5 application built for 'Any CPU' with the 'prefer 32-bit' option selected will run as a 32-bit process on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems (unlike in .NET 4.0 and earlier).
In other words, x86 and AnyCPU with 'prefer 32-bit' selected are equivalent (ignoring whether or not it can run on ARM).

However, my tests have shown that on a 64-bit system an 'AnyCPU prefer 32-bit' application (which I confirm runs 32-bit) can allocate more memory than an x86 one. I wrote a .NET 4.5 C# console app that allocates 10MB byte arrays in a loop (keeping the references of course) until it hits an OutOfMemoryException, and ran it on a 64-bit system with plenty of RAM. When built as x86 it falls over at about 1.2GB allocated. The same code built as 'Any CPU (prefer 32-bit)' gets up to 1.5GB.

Why the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out that, in Visual Studio 2015, building as 'AnyCPU (prefer 32-bit)' sets the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE bit on the executable (equivalent to running `editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE` on it), whereas it does not for an x86 build. This can be confirmed with `dumpbin /HEADERS` and looking for the line "Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses".

This is not the case for Visual Studio 2013.  The change is [apparently undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905703/compiling-c-sharp-with-any-cpu-sets-application-can-handle-large-2gb-addresse).

In theory, this should give the CLR an additional 2GB to play with. I don't know why the allocatable memory only goes up by about 300MB.

Comment: Assuming you're allocating the 10MB objects into an array or list itself, you're likely blowing up *that* array. http://bhrnjica.net/2012/07/22/with-net-4-5-10-years-memory-limit-of-2-gb-is-over/ set `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` and try. My guess is you trigger `List` resizing its internal array and resizes into an  "OOM"

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I'm creating a new 10MB byte array in each iteration, and adding a *reference* to that to a List (to prevent them being garbage collected). So the List itself is small, just a few hundred references.