# postbuild-event fails because MSB3073

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event, assembly-signing

I´m using Visual Studio 2010 to build an assembly from a C#-project with the following postbuild-event:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\tools\vsvars32.bat"
editbin /largeaddressaware "$(TargetPath)"
sn -R "$(TargetPath)" "path/to/MySigningFile.snk"
```

However when I build the project I get that error:

> Error MSB3073: The command "call "*Undefined*..\tools\vsvars32.bat" editbin /largeaddressaware "MyProgram.exe"
>   sn -R "MyProgram"
>   "path/to/MySingingFile.snk"" terminated with the following code 9009. (1, 1)

What makes me wonder is the "*undefined*" in the error. However when I open the environment-settings from within the post-build-events (Project properties --> Build Events --> Edit Post-build... --> Makros) I see that that variable should hold the value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\`[image]

EDIT: I replaced the call to `"$(DevEnvDir)..\tools\vsvars32.bat"` by the actual path where `vsvars32` is located and it worked. So it seems although I can see the variable is set appropriately within VS it is not evaluated appropriately when *building* the project.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify whether you tested in both `Debug` and `Release` builds.

If this only happens for `Release` build, then perhaps instead set on the exe in `obj` folder:

```
editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)"
```

(As mentioned in https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23694055/MSBuild-Publish-Mode-Post-Build-Event-not-executing-on-target-app-publish-files.html )

NOTE: The exact path depends on your build configuration.

If this helps, and including **both** `editbin` lines doesn't work well, then see other stackoverflow threads for correct syntax to specify one line for `Debug`, the other line for `Release`.

**UPDATE** Just tested this; it is only relevant to certain "publish" scenarios.  Probably will have no effect in your case.

---

FYI, Another related issue (though it wouldn't result in the error message mentioned) is that largeaddressaware won't work if you are using visual studio hosting for debugging.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963184/199364

Comment: I build for debug, however interesting post.