# Running into OuOfMemoryException early

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a C# application where I use Entity Framework to retrieve many objects. Unfortunately this is a requirement and probably its the wrong tool to use at this point. However, my application runs into an OutOfMemoryException at approximately 1.2GB of memory usage. How can this be? My machine has 8GB of RAM.

Comment: There other programs running, and the OS needs memory as well. You didn't expect the operating system to give you all 8GB, right?

Comment: And If you are using a 32bit system maximum process size is 4gb. Basically its not the best idea to use an O/R mapper to read so many items into memory. But you could try disabling change-tracking to optimize performance.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a redesign is necessary. Can you break the processing into more steps that touch less data so that you're loading a smaller object graph each time?

To directly address the memory consumption issue:

- If you're on a 64-bit O/S, are you compiling "Any CPU" or "x64"?
- If you're running a 32-bit O/S your process is limited to 2GB (or 3GB with `/3GB` boot.ini and `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`).
- If you're running a 32-bit process on a 64-bit O/S your process is limited to 2GB (or 4GB with `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`).

[More info on `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346480/how-to-make-a-net-application-large-address-aware).