# Managed Heap size limit for .NET executables

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I understand that garbage collection is performed when an application runs out of space in managed heap. When does this happen? What is the maximum memory size a .NET assembly can occupy and how is it determined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200348/is-there-a-memory-limit-for-a-single-net-process

Comment: The question itself is not clear enough. Do you mean by what is the maximum memory a .NET application (process) can occupy? Then it is exact duplicate of 200348. The memory limit is determined by the operating system.