# A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and trying to read a .sgy file that contains seismic data. I found out a library known as Unplugged.SEGY for reading the file. My file is of 4.12Gb,I am getting " A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" and then the program stops suddenly. This is the my code

```
using System;   
using Unplugged.Segy;  
namespace ABC   
{  
    class abc       
    {  
        static void Main(String[] args)  
        {      
            var reader = new SegyReader();  
            ISegyFile line = reader.Read(@"D:\Major\Seismic.sgy");   
            ITrace trace = line.Traces[0];   
            double mean = 0;   
            double max = double.MinValue;   
            double min = double.MaxValue;    
            foreach (var sampleValue in trace.Values)   
            {    
                mean += sampleValue / trace.Values.Count;   
                if (sampleValue < min) min = sampleValue;   
                if (sampleValue > max) max = sampleValue;   
            }  
            Console.WriteLine(mean);  
            Console.WriteLine(min);  
            Console.WriteLine(max);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Please Help me out
EDIT: I am running the application as 64-bit process

Comment: I don't think you can get more help here - you already run x64, so you either need to ask library authors about loading parts of the file or get decent amount of RAM (I would start with 16gb if you need to work with such amount of data)..

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running in 64 bit (and as long as you're in .NET 4.5+) I recommend making sure the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` flag is set to true.

In .NET there are various sizes that can be used in 32 bit applications, capping between 2-4 GB per process.  A 64 bit application can consume much more per process.

However; in both 32 bit and 64 bit a single object can only consume 2GB at most.

However; to trump that final statement again, since 4.5 and beyond, you can flag your configuration to allow objects greater than 2GB.

My final thought is that flag needs to be set in your situation.

To have a .NET process greater than 4GB it must be a 64bit process.
To have a single object greater than 2GB it must be a 64bit process, running .NET 4.5 or later, and the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` flag is set to `true`.

Comment: Wrong. For 32bit process total amount of memory (not for single object)cant be larger than 2gb. For single object maximum size is 2gb on both architectures. On 64bit process maximum allowed memory is 1tb, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200348/is-there-a-memory-limit-for-a-single-net-process

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary 32bit process can use up to 4GB on x64 machines... (otherwise good point that this answer is very misleading at best)

Comment: I tried running it as 64bit and it is not giving me any output,instead my pc is getting hanged. Can you look into the code and let me know if there is anything wrong in that? Also fyi m running this application on Windows 8 with 4Gb RAM 64-bit OS..

Comment: Michael PuckettII - please avoid adding unrelated text to post - discussion why you've made an edit to the post provided absolutely no value for solving the problem. Side note: edit did not make information in the post correct nor made answer look like an answer... If you are not sure ("try this...") - post it as comment instead.

Comment: @KhyatiAgrawal this answer is really not useful - even 4 upvotes did not make it correct or practical... In mean time you should figure out whether you are running your code as 32 or 64 bit process and add this information to the question.

Comment: Have you tried running this on a computer with more than 4GB of ram?